# Execute jar with included dependencies using Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

It was working fine when external dependencies were in the separate lib folder, but due to change in requirements jar should contain all external dependencies in it, not in a separate folder.
Can anyone Guide me how can I execute the jar file
here is my Gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'java-library-distribution'

group = 'com.MyCompany'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

description = "data-purge-service"

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}


dependencies {
    compile group: 'commons-configuration', name: 'commons-configuration', version:'1.6'
    compile group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version:'1.2.17'
    compile group: 'log4j', name: 'apache-log4j-extras', version:'1.2.17'
    compile group: 'org.quartz-scheduler', name: 'quartz', version:'2.2.1'
    compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version:'20151123'
    compile group: 'com.google.inject', name: 'guice', version:'3.0'
    compile group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version:'1.10'
    compile group: 'org.apache.velocity', name: 'velocity', version:'1.7'
    compile group: 'javax.mail', name: 'mail', version:'1.4'
    compile group: 'org.jsoup', name: 'jsoup', version:'1.8.3'
    runtime group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version:'6.0.6'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version:'3.8.1'
}

jar {
    manifest { 
        attributes "Main-Class": "com.MyCompany.datapurge.service.App"
      }


    from {
      configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }

    sourceSets {
      main {
        output.resourcesDir = "build/libs/resources"
      }
    }
}
```

When I execute generated jar it is unable to locate dependencies.
What is the way to execute it?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

"In this [tutorial](https://www.mkyong.com/gradle/gradle-create-a-jar-file-with-dependencies/), we will show you how to use Gradle build tool to create a single Jar file with dependencies."

Comment: I've followed this tutorial and there is no difference in my previous result and in current result.
Still, the programme is unable to find jars.
It throws class not found exception.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, with gradle version 5 , dependencies were only added when i used `configurations.runtimeClasspath` instead `configurations.compile`, as posted in many places.

Here the full task example:

```
task BuildJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': 'org.mycompany.mainclass'             
        )
    }
    classifier = 'all'
    baseName = 'MyJar'
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
         }
            {
                exclude "META-INF/*.SF"
                exclude "META-INF/*.DSA"
                exclude "META-INF/*.RSA"
            }
    with jar

}
```

It will create a single jar with everything.

To run the task do:

```
gradle task BuildJar //use gradew.bat for windows
```

It will place the jar at `./build/libs`

To run just do:

```
java -jar MyJar.jar
```

Use [Java Decompile](http://java-decompiler.github.io/) to analise the jar.